# Need to read specific columns in Wrangler Excel read

Tags: excel, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-data-fusion, textwrangler

I am using Wrangler to read an excel and transform.
Issue is wrangler gives option for sheet number\name, what I need is to also specify the columns to be read eg 'B1:E450'.  I could not get any combination of column declaration to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Excel source plugin in the Pipeline Studio, which would let you specify the columns and a row cap to import from the file. To use Wrangler after that, however, you'd have to manually enter the directives using the Properties view in the Studio.

Comment: Thanks @Nick for the feedback. But my excel is on Gdrive, which I imported to Cloud Storage.  Excel plugin does not seem to support any of those input systems(Gives InvalidInputException).  So was pulling through CS to Wrangler.  Do suggest if this restriction can be overcome.